# Fixed incremental increase after n number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering how to do the following: i have 20K of SQF and 10K of expenses. Is there a formula that can give every 20K of SQF 10K of costs?

i.e: 20K = 10K of costs, 40K = 20K of costs, but 30K is still 10K of costs.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `FLOOR()` function to round down to the nearest transition amount below, eg, for an amount in `A1`:

```
=FLOOR(A1,20000)/2
```

The `FLOOR()` function will round down to the nearest multiple of `20000`, then dividing by `2` will give the expenses value for that range.

Copy this formula into all the cells in rows corresponding to the values in column `A`.